# Only specific img in javascript

Tags: javascript, slider

Hello,

I'm doing a website with a javascript slider. I want to use only specific images from one folder for the slider, not all of the img in the DOM. Because I'm adding more img which shouldn't be part of the slider....

I'm using this script:

```
$(function(){
  var i= 0;
  //when the next button is clicked on
  $('.next').on("click", function(){
    //increase the display picture index by 1
    i = i + 1;
    //if we are at the end of the image queue, set the index back to 0
    if (i == $('img').length) {
      i=0;
    }
    //set current image and previous image
    var currentImg = $('img').eq(i);
    var prevImg = $('img').eq(i-1);
    //call function to animate the rotation of the images to the right
    animateImage(prevImg, currentImg);  
  });
  //when the previous button is clicked on
  $('.previous').on("click", function(){
    //if we are at the beginning of the image queue, set the previous image to the first image and the current image to the last image of the queue
    if (i==0) { 
      prevImg = $('img').eq(0);
      i=$('img').length-1;
      currentImg = $('img').eq(i);
    }
    //decrease the display picture index by 1
    else {
      i=i-1;
      //set current and previous images
      currentImg = $('img').eq(i);
      prevImg = $('img').eq(i+1);
    }
    //call function to animate the rotation of the images to the left
    animateImageLeft(prevImg, currentImg);  
  });
  //function to animate the rotation of the images to the left
  function animateImageLeft(prevImg, currentImg) {
    //move the image to be displayed off the visible container to the right
    currentImg.css({"left":"100%"});
    //slide the image to be displayed from off the container onto the visible container to make it slide from the right to left
    currentImg.animate({"left":"0%"}, 1000);
    //slide the previous image off the container from right to left
    prevImg.animate({"left":"-100%"}, 1000);
  }
  //function to animate the rotation of the images to the right
  function animateImage(prevImg, currentImg) {
    //move the image to be displayed off the container to the left
    currentImg.css({"left":"-100%"});
    //slide the image to be displayed from off the container onto the container to make it slide from left to right
    currentImg.animate({"left":"0%"}, 1000);
    //slide the image from on the container to off the container to make it slide from left to right
    prevImg.animate({"left":"100%"}, 1000); 
  }
});
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your code just does the slider part and has nothing related to to the problem you are describing. Anything you have tried so for to add "only specific images from one folder" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `$('img')` every time you need the list of images, maintain the array of the images that you want displayed. 
For example, if you can give all the img tags for the slider `class="slider-img"` to make this selection easier.

```
var imgs = $('img.slider-img');
```

And replace `$('img')` in your code with `imgs`.

Or if you want from all the images served from a specific web address or "folder", you can do the following:

```
var address = "example.com/silder_imgs";
var imgs = $('img').filter(function() { return $(this).attr(a).includes(address) });
```